# Structure scope

Tags: c, scope, structure

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "prique.h"

void main()
{
    _pqueue *test;
    queue_init(&test);
    ...
```

I don't know why I am getting this error.

> error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '{'
>   token|

The structure in header file is

```
typedef struct _pqueue
{
    int size;
    struct queue_node *first;
}_pqueue;
```

I have properly defined the structure. I saw some discussions that this error is related to scope but can't come to know how to fix it.

Comment: May be helpful if you share the structure. Also avoid just copying / pasting the error in the title of the question. It doesn't belong there. The exact error (as it appears on your screen) belongs in the body of the question.

Comment: What's in your `prique.h`? Did you close all structure definitions with an ending `;`?

Comment: Identifiers with leading underscores are reserved for the language&implementation (struct names might be an exception?). Also, main() should return int.

Comment: @wildplasser: To be more precise, in the standard, identifiers which start with an underscore and a lowercase letter are reserved if they have file scope.

Comment: Struct tags live in a separate name space (since C89/ANSI, IIRC) but now it appears the OP uses the *same* name for the struct as for the typedef, which is -at least- a very bad habit. (just like typedef is a bad habit, in most cases)

Comment: Strongly disagree that using the same identifier as struct (union/enum) tag as typedef identifier. In theory it looks bad (not the same namespace yada, yada), but in practice, on big projects, it is so much easier to have to remember only half the number of types. To have two names for essentially the same thing is imo not a good idea. That C++ essentially linked the 2 namespaces is evidence that I'm not alone with that opinion.

Comment: Question at OP: What is `struct queue_node` ? What is the prototype of `queue_init();` ? Didn't you forget a ; somewhere else in your .h file.

Comment: Forgot: and preceding every type with `struct` or `union` while good at a auto-documentation level has the backside of making the signatures of functions and typecasts horribly long and unwieldy, which often pushes people to split long lines making them again ungreppable.

Comment: **Which specific line is giving you that error?**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the problem here but some compilers do not recognize void main(), so:

```
int main()
```

Otherwise it might be something in your prique.h module...

Also, if your queue_node is defined in the same manner (typedef struct queue_node {...} queue_node) then you probably don't need struct keyword:

```
typedef struct _pqueue
{
    int size;
    queue_node *first;
} _pqueue;
```

Comment: There's also a second violation of C correctness. The leading _ is reserved for the compiler implementation and should not be used by the programmer. Neither that nor the `void main` are the cause of his error message.

Answer (score 0):

You must be aware that you can compile your *.h file also. Do this:

`gcc -Wall prique.h`

to make sure that your header file declarations are all correct.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that `queue_node` is the same as `pqueue`.  If that is the case
then this should clear up the problem. If not, then `queue_node` is probably not defined in your include file.

The code below is probably what you wanted.

```
typedef struct pqueue {
    int size;
    struct pqueue *first;
} pqueue_t;

void
main()
{
    pqueue_t *test;

}
```